# Error when navigating to a component route

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 6 with typescript and trying to navigate from a component route (RegisterComponent) to another component route (ProfileComponent) using navigate (using routerLink also doesn't work). I tried many examples I found but I keep encountering the same error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property >'removeEventListener' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeEventListener' of undefined

My code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
//hidden imports ...

export const appRoutes: Routes = [

       {path: '', component: RegisterComponent}, 
       {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent}, 


]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CustomFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [ RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class RegisterComponent {
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

test(){
    this.router.navigate(["../profile"], {relativeTo: this.route});
    //this.router.navigate(["/profile"], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }
}
```

**register.component.html**

```
<div (click)="test()">click</div>
```

Comment: Post the code of ProfileComponent

Comment: That code is pretty huge so i wouldn't like to post it. But anyway, i tried with a new empty Component replacing ProfileComponent and it has nothing to do with that component or the code inside it. The error still appears.

Comment: What happens when you try to load that route directly using browser location bar.. I mean by simply typing localhost:4200/profile..

Comment: when I try it manually by typing, it works without problems and throws no error

Comment: Can you just try  this.router.navigate(["/profile"]);

Comment: Ok, I found the problem and now it works. I had an OnDestroy() implementation in RegisterComponent which I wasn't handling the right way. The error description was kind of misleading so I didn't think about it. Thank you for the effort anyway.